# Which Method for making a time series stationary would work better?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, lags, augmented-dickey-fuller

If there is a possible multiplicative time series (seasonality increasing marginally over time) that has a large trend component and a smaller seasonal component, would a Lag 1 difference to remove the trend and then a subsequent Lag 12 difference to remove seasonality be better or a log transformation and a Lag 1 Difference to stabilize variance. Both plots would look stationary and satisfy adf, which would be better a approach?

Comment: You can take the logarithm to turn mutiplicative into additive. Differencing is only warranted for series that have unit roots. When applied in other circumstances, it creates the problem of overdifferencing (introduces a unit root into errors, makes them autocorrelated and increases their variance). Consider a seasonal ARMA (SARMA) model instead.